# Get all rows where one row for a particular value matches regex

Tags: r

I wasn't really sure how to phrase the title but here goes.

I have a dataset as follows

```
HNum       Grade
1234       LGD
1234       NDBE
1234       NDBE
5678       NDBE
5678       HGD
9765       LGD
7556       LGD
7556       NDBE
```

If a row has LGD in it I want to get all the rows for the HNum that is associated with so the output would be:

```
HNum       Grade
1234       LGD
1234       NDBE
1234       NDBE
9765       LGD
7556       LGD
7556       NDBE
```

I really don't know how to do this as I guess it would rely of matching a row in Grade, getting the HNum and then re-grepping the original dataset to get the rows with that `HNum`.

I can do the grep something like:

```
LGDSubset <- unique(df[grep("LGD", df$Grade,perl=TRUE), ])
HNumLGD<-as.vector(LGDSubset$HNum)
```

which should give me a vector of unique `HNum`'s

but what I don't know how to do is then iterate across this vector and pull out all the rows from the original dataframe based on each `HNum`

Comment: That doesn't really explain much

Comment: Why the row `5678,NDBE` is present in the output? `5678` never has `LGD`. I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks @nicola. No you're not missing something. I am. Corrected it

Comment: I think your expected output is incorrect (`HNum` : `5678` doesn't have `LGD`. Otherwise you can probably do something like this: `df[df$HNum %in% df$HNum[grep("LGD",df$Grade)],]
`

Comment: @mtoto comment should solve your problem. However, it seems that you are not including the row `7556,NDBE` which should be part of the output, I guess.

Comment: If there's a reason this isn't a straight-forward one-pass application of `grepl` it's not apparent. Perhaps you should add the desired outcome and `dput` the data.

Comment: Aha. @nicola. Yes I had erased the wrong row. Thanks

Comment: I dont understand Hack-R. grepl will just return the rows when LGD is present not all the rows for the HNum when LGD is present just once for that HNum

Comment: `grepl` will return the `Grade` that match. When a `Grade`matches, you obtain a `HNum`. That can be used to select in your dataframe.

Comment: Hi mtoto please post as an answer. That works.

Comment: Yes I understand that grepl will obtain HNum but the point of the question is to understand how to then select all the rows with that HNum. Just telling me to use grepl doesnt really help if you don't tell me how this second and crucial bit can be done.

Comment: And if someone could please tell me why the perfectly valid question has been marked down I'd be grateful.

Comment: beacause there is no reproducible example ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something there is a reproducible example- it is the main body of the question. Please don't mark questions down for no reason particularly when there is nothing wrong with them..unless you have a different definition of example

Comment: I did nothing suh as marking down the question. Maybe reproducible would look like a `dput` so you can copy-paste the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could subset `df` by the `HNum` values that occur when `Grade` includes `"LGD"`:

```
df[df$HNum %in% df$HNum[grep("LGD",df$Grade)],] 
#  HNum Grade
#1 1234   LGD
#2 1234  NDBE
#3 1234  NDBE
#6 9765   LGD
#7 7556   LGD
#8 7556  NDBE
```